# Getting error while fetching data from db in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get data that match with my giving time, i pass time as a string for now but it gives error,

here is my code

```
$final_trade = FinalTrade::where('user_id', $user_id)
        ->where(Carbon::parse('created_at')->format('h:i:s'), '9.30.00')
        ->first();
```

here is the error,

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (created_at) at position 0 (c): The timezone could not be found in the database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereTime` directly without parsing,

```
$final_trade = FinalTrade::where('user_id', $user_id)
               ->whereTime('created_at', '=', '9:30:00')
                ->first();
```

Comment: this works, what if i need to compere time and add hours in it ?

Comment: actually i need to get time between range, i just have start time, so i need to add hour in it like start date and end date

Comment: @MuhammadArslan, for that you may use accessor, `getCreatedAtAttribute` and u can return whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass date in the parse not string https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ 
Read the docs

Comment: what do you means ?

Comment: First off there is error in your syntax where expects first parameter to be column's name and you should pass date format like `Carbon::parse('2018-02-18 10:00:01')` like so

Answer (score 0):

The first field in the where method must be the name of the table field

```
$final_trade = FinalTrade::where('user_id', $user_id)
        ->where('created_at', '9.30.00')
        ->first();
```

please read this [laravel query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)

Comment: this always return null

Comment: this is the actual date i have, 2018-05-25 09:30:00

Comment: if you want to do what you need during the search, or save the time in the created_at table, or use CARBON to format the time to the date and time. although it would be more correct if the table saved the time and not the datetime